# Caching compiled css and js and clears cache on changes in files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control, mod-deflate, mod-expires

I have been going through lots of article, where a proper example for caching mechanism is not penned down. All tutorials describes about that and a single line demo which, I guess, never really optimizes. I have compiled css and js using grunt.

I have included

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

in my .htaccess file.

This, actually says, to cache the content and whenever any changes occur force the browser to use new files.

I do not actually see any changes in DOM Loaded content or in Load Time and everytime, the compiled css and js takes files from server and caches after 5-7 reloading. I guess the cache, which it performs, uses default browser cache.

So How would I use a caching mechanism so that it serves pages quickly and clears the cache when any changes effects the css and JS?

I am using PHP as my application. A better example for doing that with code would be really helpful.

Comment: Change `access X <time>` to `modification plus x <time>`

Comment: That actually didnot help..Instead of compresing the size it got overheaded

Comment: Then you're probably looking for [`mod_deflate`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_deflate)

Comment: If you want resources to be updated when modification timestamps of the underlying files change – then using mod_expires makes very little sense to begin with.